# What command will let me know the last folder that I have moved

Tags: shell, linux-mint

Is there a way to find out which folder that I have moved recently?

Comment: Can you check history of commands?

Comment: I moved the folder by drag and drop. I didn't move the folder by command.

Comment: When you move the folder, the time stamp on the folder does not change, but the one on the containing folder changes.  If you do not have a lot of movement, you may be able to correlate which two folders have changed timestamps and infer the one that you moved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `bash`, you can go back to the previous folder with `cd -` or find the command history with `history`. Directory changes `history | grep 'cd '`

Comment: The question is about moving folders from one place to another, though.

Comment: the question is not clear at all. Just saw the comment